# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

My aim is to copy yesterday mail items to the external folder in my computer I'm getting this error in `"mailitem = Item"` this line.

below is my code:

```
    Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("user", "Password", "domain")
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("acce@pac.com.in")
    Dim pageSize As Integer = 100
    Dim offset As Integer = 0
    Dim view As New ItemView(pageSize, offset)
    Dim returnValue As FindItemsResults(Of Item)
    returnValue = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view)
    Dim subject As String
    Dim receiveDate As Date
    Dim maxDate As Date = getLatestDate()
    For Each Item In returnValue
        receiveDate = Item.DateTimeReceived
        If receiveDate > maxDate Then
            Dim strDirPLE As String
            Dim strDirCust As String
            Dim strSaveName As String
            strDirPLE = "D:\test1\"
            strDirCust = "D:\test2\"
            Dim mailitem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
            mailitem = Item
            subject = Item.Subject.Replace(":", "")
            subject = Item.Subject.Replace(".", "")
            strSaveName = subject & Format(Now, " ddmmyyyyhhnnss") & ".msg"
             If (mailitem.From.Contains("@pac.com.in")) Then
                If (Item.Subject.Contains("CId") AndAlso Item.Subject.Contains("pId")) Then

                    mailitem.SaveAs(strcon1)
                Else
                    mailitem.SaveAs(strcon2)
                End If
            End If

        End If
        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

The error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'

Comment: See [How to: Work with Exchange Mail items in EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Comment: Not related but you have a small bug on the `subject` lines. You're setting it and then you're resetting it. On the second `.Replace` you should use `subject.Replace(".", "")`. You could put both onto one line

Comment: Why do you keep removing your code?

Comment: I've asked you _why_ and you've not responded. Can I now please ask you **not** to vandalise your own post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving it as EML not MSG. Sorry vb.net is not my first language.

```
Shared Sub ExportMIMEEmail(service As ExchangeService)
    Dim inbox As Folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)
    Dim view As New ItemView(1)
    view.PropertySet = New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)
    ' This results in a FindItem call to EWS.
    Dim results As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = inbox.FindItems(view)
    For Each item As var In results
        Dim props As New PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent)
        ' This results in a GetItem call to EWS.
        Dim email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, props)
        Dim emlFileName As String = "C:\export\email.eml"
        ' Save as .eml.
        Using fs As New FileStream(emlFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            fs.Write(email.MimeContent.Content, 0, email.MimeContent.Content.Length)
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

This was modified from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Although not in the question, Avi may want to look at EWS' handy event handlers as a next step to add a level of automation.